# How to calculate cumulative sums in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, cumulative-sum

I am preparing for interviews and came across this question while practicing some SQL questions recently asked in Amazon. I could not find the table though, but the question is as follows:

Find the cumulative sum of the top 10 most profitable products of the last 6 months for customers in Seattle.

**Does the approach to solving this type of query look correct? If not, what would be the best way to approach this problem?**

```
SELECT t.day,
       t.product_count,
       @running_total:=@running_total + t.product_count AS cumulative_sum
FROM
( SELECT
  date(purchase_date) as day,
  count(product_id) as product_count
  FROM products
  where day > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  AND customer_city = 'Seattle'
  GROUP BY day 
  ORDER BY product_count desc) t
JOIN (SELECT @running_total:=0) r
ORDER BY t.day
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: If you can't install a dbms on your computer, there are a few on-line services for ad-hoc quries, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/.

Comment: Nowadays you would rather use the window function `COUNT OVER` to get a cumulative sum (aka running total) and not use MySQL's old variable approach. As to the tables: It is unlikely for a product table to contain a customer city. There will more likely be three tables: product, customer and purchase. If you `ORDER BY t.day` and `LIMIT 10` then you get the first ten days, not the ten top selling products.

Comment: One more thing: You have `ORDER BY` in a subquery. This can be considered superfluous, as a subquery result is an unordered data set by definition. You should not be building up on that sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
select day,product_count,
sum(product_count) over (order by t.day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cumulative_sum from (
SELECT
  date(purchase_date) as day,
  count(product_id) as product_count
  FROM products
  where day > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  AND customer_city = 'Seattle'
  GROUP BY day 
  ORDER BY product_count desc
)t
```

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is the default window frame for `ORDER BY`, and so you may omit it.

Comment: @coderWorld please right down your review in this code.

Comment: without `order by ` can't use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Piyush Kachhadiya: You have misunderstood. Tim says you can remove `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, because `ORDER BY t.day` already implicates this (`ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is the default when using `ORDER BY`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes understand that says but not possible without  order by `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`. if you know any method without order by tell me please.

Comment: You forgot the limit 10